# How to make sure web crawler works for site hosted on AWS S3 and uses AJAX

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, web-crawler, google-crawlers

Google webmaster guide explains that web server should handle requests for url that contains _escaped_fragment_ (The crawler modifies www.example.com/ajax.html#!mystate to www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=mystate)

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992

My site is located on AWS S3 and I have no web server to handle such requests. How can I make sure the crawler gets feed and my site gets index?

Answer (score 0):

S3 hosted sites are static html. No POST handling, no PHP renders, no nothing... So, Why do you care about Google indexing AJAX sites?

For a static website, simply upload well formed robots.txt and sitemap.xml files to your root path.